# Cosine similarity with string as input from operator - FLOAT ERROR

Tags: python, string, compiler-errors

I want to create a sort of comparator that given in input a sentence, from an operator, the program evaluate, trough the cosine similarity, if there are similar sentence inside a dataset.
What I have done till now is:

```
text = pd.read_excel("Database1.xlsx", usecols='C'))
new_input = input('Insert the sentence: ')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
print(tfidf_matrix.shape)

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
a = cosine_similarity(new_input, tfidf_matrix)
print(a)
```

But I obtain an error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'hello world'
```

I try to solve it with:

```
new_input = float(input('Insert the sentence: '))
```

If I correctly understand, the problem is due to the impossobility of transforming the input string 'hello world' in float due to the presence of spaces, but I need the presence of spaces in input.

How can i solve the situation?
Thank you very much for helping

Comment: What outcome do you desire from `float('hello world')`?

Comment: You can not type cast `'hello world'` to a `float` value

Comment: @ThePyGuy I understand that I can’t type cast 'hello world' to a float value due to the presence of spaces, but the operator that create the input pass to the program a sentence and this means there will be spaces, my problem is that I don’t know how to manage it

Comment: @Luca You are not getting my point, it's not because of space only. Any non-numeric literal can not be type cast to `float` and that includes alphabets as well. For example, you can type cast `'5'` to float but you can not type cast `'h'` to float.